# How can I filter a Haystack SearchQuerySet for None on an IntegerField

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

This is driving me a bit mad but seems like it should be simple.

I'm using Django and Haystack and have a search index including an IntegerField which allows null. This is based on a related model in Django, but I don't think this matters. eg:

```
class ThingIndex(indexes.ModelSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    group = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='group__id', null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Thing
```

I sometimes want my Haystack query to return items with None/Null for this field, so I'm filtering in the search form's __init__, but I can't get a query to do this. The most obvious way I tried was:

```
self.searchqueryset.filter(group__isnull=True)  # how to do it on a regular Django queryset
```

But this returns no records.

Right now I'm working around it with this:

```
self.searchqueryset.exclude(group__in=range(1,100))
```

Which works, but obviously isn't the way it should be done :)

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I feel this question was not answered. It seems the op was asking how to filter for null entries using haystack.query.SearchQuerySet with an ElasticSearch backend.

In the example above, replace

```
self.searchqueryset.filter(group__isnull=True)
```

with

```
self.searchqueryset.filter(_missing_='group')
```

Not intuitive, but its the only way I have gotten this to work so far.

Comment: Thanks for this. If possible, please add the source for this answer.

Comment: @Mangolisk thanks, this works for me with `.exclude` too. Do you know how can I can search for objects excluding those that have field `a` missing **and** field `b` missing? Example with obviously invalid syntax: `orphans = children.exclude(_missing_='mother' AND _missing_='father')` - thanks!

Comment: Answering myself: solved using SQ: https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/searchquery_api.html#sq-objects

Answer (score 14):

If you are using ElasticSearch, the solution can be done without patching, just using native ElasticSearch:

```
from haystack.inputs import Raw
self.searchqueryset.exclude(group = Raw("[* TO *]"))
```

Other way around, filter all documents that have non-emtpy group field:

```
from haystack.inputs import Raw
self.searchqueryset.filter(group = Raw("[* TO *]"))
```

This could work for SOLR too and for other Haystack backends applying the same concept but with specific syntax of the backend search language.

References:

- [Elastic search query syntax](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges_2)
- [Haystack backend implementation for elasticsearch](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py#L772)
- [Haystack Raw input field](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/inputtypes.html#raw)
- Thanks to @AlexParakhnevich who provided this [link](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/commit/9332a91a7f0e4b33d7e20aa892d156305c12dfe3) which served me as an inspiration.
- Good to know that Elasticsearch also supports special and more robust ["missing" filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html)

Comment: nice.. just one thing you have a TYPO, it should be `self.searchqueryset.exclude(group = Raw("[* TO *]"))`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SOLR, you'd probably like to have a look at the following links:

1) https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/commit/9332a91a7f0e4b33d7e20aa892d156305c12dfe3 
2) https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/163

There's a patch for SOLR, allowing such queries, but for other backends there's probably none.

Comment: Thanks! Really useful. Not using SOLR, we're using ElasticSearch. Oh well.